# Why agg() in PySpark is only able to summarize one column of a DataFrame at a time?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For the below dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[('Alice',4.300),('Bob',7.677)], schema=['name','High'])
```

When I try to find min & max I am only getting min value in output.

```
df.agg({'High':'max','High':'min'}).show()
```

```
+-----------+
|min(High)  |
+-----------+
|    2094900|
+-----------+
```

Why can't `agg()` give both max & min like in Pandas?

Comment: if someone is still wondering on _Why can't agg() give both max & min like in Pandas?_ is **it will not work on pandas either** because both agg() in pandas and pyspark accepts a dictionary and as we know dictionary can't have more than one key with same name, hence `df.agg({'High':'max','High':'min'}).show()` is really  `df.agg({'High':'min'}).show()` because `'High':'max'` was rewritten to `'High':'min'`

Comment: CONTD: syntax in pandas will be `df.agg({'High': {'min(High)': np.min, 'max(High)': np.max}})`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg):

> **agg(*exprs)**
>
> Compute aggregates and returns the result as a DataFrame.
>
> The available aggregate functions are avg, max, min, sum, count.
>
> If exprs is a single dict mapping from string to string, then the key is the column to perform aggregation on, and the value is the aggregate function.
>
> Alternatively, exprs can also be a list of aggregate Column expressions.
>
> Parameters:    **exprs** – a dict mapping from column name (string) to aggregate functions (string), or a list of Column.

You can use a list of column and apply the function that you need on every column, like this:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F

>>> df.agg(F.min(df.High),F.max(df.High),F.avg(df.High),F.sum(df.High)).show()
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|min(High)|max(High)|avg(High)|sum(High)|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      4.3|    7.677|   5.9885|   11.977|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Databricks with Spark 2.4 and Python 3.2.